# Unable to rhc setup to my openshift cluster

Tags: ruby, openshift-origin

I am unable to setup my server with rhc setup. This is my output

```
This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace,
and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running server_stage
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://cluster01vt.office.noris.gr:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://cluster01vt.office.noris.gr:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
DEBUG: Certificate validation failed: self signed certificate

The server's certificate is self-signed, which means that a secure connection
can't be established to 'cluster01vt.office.noris.gr:8443'.

You may bypass this check, but any data you send to the server could be
intercepted by others.

Connect without checking the certificate? (yes|no): y
DEBUG: Connecting to https://cluster01vt.office.noris.gr:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://cluster01vt.office.noris.gr:8443/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: SSL Verification failed -- Using self signed cert
DEBUG:    code 403   16 ms
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Keep in mind that I am getting a 403 error when I try to visit the page with my browser. The JSON response:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "User \"system:anonymous\" cannot \"get\" on \"/broker/rest/api\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {},
  "code": 403
}
```

Why doesn't the rhc ask me for credentials ? Any ideas?

Comment: Um, exactly which version of Origin are you running?

Comment: [root@cluster01vt opt]# origin version
origin v1.3.3
kubernetes v1.3.0+52492b4
etcd 2.3.0+git

Comment: You don't use the `rhc` tool with current versions of Origin. Did you stumble into a bad Internet tutorial? Go back to the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`rhc` is the command line utility for the old version of OpenShift.

You need to use `oc` instead. See the [docs](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/cli_reference/index.html).